# driver.find_elements_by_id('fakebox-input').send_keys('site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "python developer" AND "London"') showing attribute error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[driver.find_elements_by_id('fakebox-input') showing attribute error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckvMY.png)

When I am running it through anaconda ipython prompt, it is giving this error message -

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

So this was my code -

```
search_query = driver.find_elements_by_id('fakebox-input')#that's the ID I am getting from the chrome inspection image I attached 
search_query.send_keys('site:linkedin.com/in/ AND "python developer" AND "London"')
```

Also when I am checking search query, it's an empty list

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get multiple elements by id, it return a list.
Try instead the function `search_query = driver.find_element_by_id()` note that I use "element" instead of "elements"

EXPLAIN: Each query function in selenium has 2 versions, one for a multiple elements (This function return a list of elements that match your condition), the other one is for a single element (this function will do the same as the first but will return only the first in the list. In addition, this function will throw an error if no element was fount that match the condition.)

All of these function has the same name but one is for multiple elements, such as `find_elements_by_id`. And the other is for a single element `find_element_by_id`.

You need to find a single element if you want to send keys, therefore you can use either of the following

```
driver.find_elements_by_id(your_id)[0]
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id(your_id)
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="fakebox-input"]"}`, is the current error now :(

Comment: Can you please take a look at the image? I feel like the id is not probably correct?

Comment: I updated the answer to be more helpful. In this case the driver cant find the element with your id and that's why you get an error. This is, however, not relevant to the question you asked, please open a new thread if you wish to ask another question

Comment: There can be many reasons for this error, maybe it's in a different frame and so you cant access it. Again this is a different question than the one you asked' please close this thread and open a new one for it

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sendkey with list object. if you want to  use sendkey use find_element_by_id instead of find_elements_by_id.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until_not(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "fakebox-input"))).send_keys("Your Data")
```

Add below imports to your solution :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: what is driver here ? In may case it was - 'driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\pushp\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')' And this is giving this error - 'AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'send_keys'' :(

Comment: I have windows64 but the chromedriver version is 32, since that was the only thing available on the website. Should I need to do anything else?

Comment: no thats correct , can youprovide your url I will check from my end ?

Comment: Thanks so much @Dipak. I realized that earlier I was getting a google page like the one attached with the question when I was first going to some another page through driver and then just going to another tab in that driver-controlled chrome page. Now I am adding driver.get('www.google.com') and got a page which looks kinda different from the earlier one and it is working fine now :D